# Partial Derivative to Second Degree Conceptual

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $u(x,y)=f(x+y)+g(x-y)$. How can I calculate $\partial u/ \partial x$, $\partial u/ \partial y$, $\partial^2 u/ \partial x^2$, $\partial^2 u/ \partial y^2$ in terms of derivatives of $f$ and $g$.

So I thought of making a new variable such that say, $v=x+y, w=x-y$ and then substituting. But I don’t know where this will lead to. Can someone help me on this path?

Comment: Then for the first term $$\frac{\partial f(v)}{\partial x} = \frac{df(v)}{dv}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Comment: Yes I found that

Answer (score 1):

The two rules you need are

$$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\p{(f+g)}x=\p fx+\p gx$$

and

$$\p{f(g(x,y))}x=f'(g(x,y))\p{g(x,y)}x\;.$$

Comment: Can you just put the answers so I can check?

Comment: No. But you can use this to get the answers and then I can check.

Comment: for partial du/dx is it (1+y)f'(v)+(1-y)f'(w)?

Comment: @sophie: Almost. Since only $x$ and $y$ appear in the problem statement, we can safely assume that the intended meaning of the ambiguous partial derivative operators is that $x$ and $y$ are being considered as two independent variables and $\partial/\partial x$ refers to the variation with $x$ at constant $y$. What is the variation of $y$ at constant $y$?

Comment: Is it 1?  Or is that wrong?

Comment: @sophie: How can something constant vary? Think of a function of $x$ and $y$ as a landscape plotted over the $x$-$y$-plane. The function $h(x,y)=y$ rises linearly in the $y$ direction and is constant in the $x$ direction. The partial derivative $\partial/\partial x$ measures the rate of variation in the $x$ direction, at constant $y$, and in this direction $h(x,y)=y$ is constant, independent of $x$. What is the derivative of a constant independent of $x$ with respect to $x$?